# Batch file to log off users isn't working

Tags: batch-file, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-task-scheduler

I have this batch file being called from the Task Scheduler every morning at 1am:

```
echo Logging off all users on %DATE% at %TIME% >>%cd%\logoffeveryone.log
query session >session.txt
for /f "skip=1 tokens=3," %%i in (session.txt) DO logoff %%i
del session.txt
```

I went to see if it is working and this is the results:

[image]

As you can see from the LOGON TIME they have some users that were logged in over 2 weeks ago and they were not logged off.

I have the task running with the highest privileges:

[image]

The history shows completed and no errors while running it.

Any ideas why it's not logging off the users? Could it be the STATE they are in when the script runs?

**EDIT#1**

For clarity, here is the ACTION settings of the task:

[image]

I already had the starting directory set to `d:\scripts`.

And the permissions of the directory where I have the scripts folder:

[image]

Comment: Going to assume the script runs fine when you run it manually.  When you run a batch file in the background, the working directory becomes SYSTEM32. The user may not have permissions to write to that folder.  I would specify the full path to the files you are writing to and reading from.

Comment: @Squashman I added additional information to my post, hope that answers your questions.

Comment: Given the assumption that the blurred out `USERNAME`'s do not contain any spaces or tab characters, what do you expect these commands to do: `logoff 2`, `logoff 37`, `logoff Disc`, `logoff Disc`, `logoff 47`, `logoff 49`, `logoff Disc` ...etc? Perhaps you could begin by removing `tokens=3,`!

Comment: Have you considered just setting a Group Policy?  You can set a timeout value for disconnected and idle sessions.